# How to read Terminal Services Manager idle time

Tags: windows-server-2003, remote-desktop

I opened Terminal Services Manager today on my Win2k3 server and it shows something like this:

```
User         State          Idle Time       Logon Time
Jake         Active         1               9/20/2012
Silvia       Disconnected   3+00:43
```

From the help docs, idle time:

> Displays the number of minutes that have elapsed since the last keyboard or mouse input from a session.

OK, Jake has been idle for 1 minute, makes sense. But "3+00:43" to me does not compute. What does this mean? How long has Silvia been idle?

Bonus question: Why is logon time empty for Silvia? Sure she's disconnected, but she is logged on so there should be a time there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `3` there is the number of *days* the user's been idle, so three days, 43 minutes, or 72 hours, 43 minutes.  (Not sure why they didn't just display the idle time like that, but they didn't).

The formatting of that output is:

`# of days` + `hours:minutes`

No answer to your bonus question off the top of my head, but maybe I can replicate that at work and get you answer... if not, I'd just blame Silvia.  Silly luser, log off by using the `Log Off` option, not the `x` in the top right of the screen.  Tsk, tsk.